# Oracle BI report consistency

Tags: oracle-bi

Does Oracle BI provide means of ensuring report consistency in a scenario with an asynchronously loading data mart? I.e., if a report queries tables A and B, and these two tables are loaded asynchronously, is there a way to ensure that the report will be consistent regardless of the underlying data?

Answer (score 0):

No, that's up to you. It gives you the tools to use pre-existing means (like data load metadata lookups) but you have to make things consistent yourself.